# Ruby on rails, error in unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I has one-to many relationship, one group has many servers. To test this relation, i write this test, but it work only when I uncomented line. Why?

```
test 'Group can include server' do
    group = groups(:default)
    group.servers << servers(:default)
    # Test work, when I uncomment this line:
    # assert_instance_of Array, group.servers
    group.save
    assert_instance_of Server, group.servers.first
end
```

Comment: Does it work when you *comment* or *uncomment* that line? Does *this* code work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `group.servers` *isn't* an `Array`. It behaves a lot like one, but it's actually an instance of [ActiveRecord::Association::HasManyAssociation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/HasManyAssociation). Its ancestor class (ActiveRecord::Association::AssociationProxy) actually passes even `class` through to an underlying object, so `group.servers.class` does give `Array`, but it isn't really one.

**Edit:** Quick note to say that, while I'm pretty sure this is the reason for your failure, it doesn't make complete sense; in my test apps, the equivalent of `group.servers.instance_of? Array` is `true`, and the [source](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_instance_of) of `assert_instance_of` implies that should be good enough.